# Can Chrome or FireFox force https request instead of http request?

Tags: http, google-chrome, firefox, https

I have pretty strange situation. I'm working on domain example.net and some of its pages are delivered via https and some over http (but http resources can be accessed using https too). When I access page http://example.net/page1.html delivered using http protocol Chrome executes HTTP request. Then, when I access https://example.net/page2.html via HTTPS Chrome executes HTTPS request. Till now everything is as it should be. I then try to access http://example.net/page1.html via HTTP but Chrome executes HTTPS request.

My first thought was that http://example.net/page1.html redirects to https://example.net/page1.html but this is not the case. Here's list of things I've checked:

- in 'Network' tab in Web Developer Tools when accessing http://example.net/page1.html (for the second time) I see entry for  http request that has 'Finished' status, 'Other' in initiator column, 13 bytes and it's finished in 5 ms (other requests to the host are in 150ms+ range) - clearly Chrome cancels the request. The request is followed by https://example.net/page1.html request.
- I've confirmed using Wireshark that first packet sent to the example.net server when accessing http://example.net/page1.html for the second time is to port 443, so it's not the server that does the redirect to force https.
- switching to 'Private browsing' mode does not help, http requests are still changed to https requests,
- I don't have HTTPS Everywhere or anything similar installed,
- wiping out browser history seems to do the trick, however I need to figure out why Chrome and FF insist on https,
- other web servers seem to work fine and I'm free to switch between http and https,
- IE does not force https.

Is there some new security policy, server header etc. that forces Chrome and FireFox to force https after browser finds out that server responds to https? I'm working on newest Chrome (33.0.1750.154) and FF (28.0).

Comment: Might the server previously have returned [`301 Moved Permanently`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) redirecting the HTTP URI to the HTTPS one?  Such responses are cacheable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out there's a header web server can set during HTTPS response to tell browser to force HTTPS on all requests. You can read more about it here [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)